# Soap Connection

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I'm trying to create a Soap connection.  The error I'm getting is:

SOAP Fault: (faultcode: Client faultstring: looks like we got no XML document)

I have my code below. Any suggestions of where to look from here?

```
$myproxy = new SoapClient('https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl');
try {
  $sess = $myproxy->login('user','password');
} catch(Soapfault $err) {
  $error_message = "SOAP Error: (faultcode: {$err->faultcode}\n" ."faultstring: {$err->faultstring})";
  echo $error_message;
}
```

I've tried troubleshooting the WSDL file by going to https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl, saving it as an XML file and running it through wsdl-analyzer.com.  The error I got was:

The structure of your WSDL is
types (1)
message (12)
portType (1)
binding (1)
service (1)
message (288)
But should be
types
messages
portTypes
bindings
services

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `__getLastResponse()` method in the catch block. This method examines the server response. The `$myproxy->__getLastResponse();` displays the error message that is thrown during the last SOAP response which will lead you in the right direction.

And, also include the `array('trace' => 1)` param while initializing the SoapClient.

```
$myproxy = new SoapClient(
'https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl', 
array('trace' => 1)
);
try {
  $sess = $myproxy->login('user','password');
} catch(Soapfault $err) {
  echo $myproxy->__getLastResponse();
}
```

Comment: #7 /home/site/public_html/index.php(68): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
which corresponds with:
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);